# Installing docker on a Pi zero W (or a pi zero2)

Tags: pi-zero-w, arm

I am Trying to install docker on a 32bit Arm.
Has anyone succedded and has a modus operandi?

Comment: If you really need a *modus operandi*, I would go with something like "never run a changing system". If you need a step-by-step instructions, I would rather search for "tutorial", "manual" or "how-to".

Comment: Seriously though, have you tried `curl -sSL https://get.docker.com | sh`?

Answer (score 1):

I do not recommend using Docker on Pi Zero.
There are not much docker images available for ARMv6. To save you from trouble you should use Pi 2 or newer or Pi Zero 2.
Also you should consider the limited memory amount of Pi Zero 2. All full-size Pis have at least 1GB.

Otherwise follow the installation instructions on the official docker page:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/